# How to display a .bin image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bin

So I'm sure this is an incredibly simple question, but I'm having trouble reading and displaying data from a .bin file. Basically, I have an image (256x256, 8 bits per pixel) that I'm trying to read in and display. While I can get this to work for a .jpg or .tif, I can't get it to work for a .bin file. Here's my code as of now:

```
file = fopen('image.bin', 'r');
A = fread(file);
imshow(A) %not sure if this is correct...
% imshow(file) doesn't work
% imshow('image.bin') doesn't work either
fclose(file);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A `.bin` file is very ambiguous.  It could be anything.  Do you know if this is a raw image?  Does this file contain the raw image pixels themselves?  Also, a link to the `.bin` file would help to answer your question.  If it's a binary file, doing `fread` will read the entire contents of the file into an array, then you need to **reshape** the array so that it becomes an image.  Also, because your image is 8 bits per pixel, try doing this with your `fread` call: `A = fread(file, 256*256, 'uint8=>uint8'); `.  Next, do this to reshape the image: `A = reshape(A, 256, 256).';` Now try `imshow(A)`

Comment: I'm not sure if the file is an image or just raw image pixels, but the code you gave worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Bahaha, if it worked, then the data are raw image pixels.  Cool!  Mind if I write an answer and can you accept it?

Comment: I wrote an answer anyway.  Please accept when you get the chance :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `.bin` file consists of raw image intensities that are stored in a binary file.  Your `fread` call will simply read the contents of the file into an array, but you need to be careful.  By default, the values will be read in as 64-bit `double` values in MATLAB so what will happen is that a single `double` value will contain **8** image pixels.  As such, what you need to do is modify how the values are being read in with `fread`.  Specifically, you need to do this:

```
A = fread(file, 256*256, 'uint8=>uint8');
```

This is saying that you are going to read a total of 256 x 256 image pixels, where the input binary file stores the data in unsigned 8-bit integers.  After, the data is read into MATLAB as the same type.  Now, what you need to do next is to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the array so that it becomes a 256 x 256 image.

However, because `fread` reads in the data in **column-major**, each row of this reshaped image would be placed into the columns, and so you need to **transpose** the reshaped matrix when you're done.  Specifically:

```
A = reshape(A, 256, 256).';
```

Now, `A` would be your 256 x 256 image that you are seeking.  You can now show this image with `imshow(A);`.